# SeleniumWebdriver - size of collection selected elements

Tags: xpath, selenium, webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I would like to select all childs and grandchilds and grand-grand etc. in root div,
But problem is: when collection of these selected elements has size greater than 55, The collection cut first half of elements, 
I have 98 divs in my parent div overall, but selenium doesn`t know to sum them.

Comment: Wow. Does it happen in all browsers? What is your Selenium version and which language binding are you using? I'm going to try it right away...

Comment: Well. With Selenium 2.30.0, IE8 and Java bindings, I can't confirm this, the returned collection is always ok no matter how large I try to get. Can you show a working testcase?

Comment: yes, but I will be in work on monday again, ...now I don t have a source at home , thank you for answer while.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this code and see how many elements are displayed, for me it showed 1000+ elements:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://yahoo.com");
    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*"));
    System.out.println("number of elements in the page: " + allElements.size());
    driver.quit();
}
```

It doesn't really matter which elements are selected, you can change the xpath to `By.xpath("//div")` and it'll still show you 300+ results.

Could it be that your IDE only displays partial info during debug?